# keeping a floating button in place relative to window and within window bounds using QT5.11

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I'm using Qt 5.11 and I have a movable floating small button that I would like to keep always in its place relative to the window when resizing or maximize/minimizing the window and would also want it to remain inside the window area never get outside of visible windows area.
i have the following code that somewhat does what I need but isn't working properly all the time! for example sometimes its a little bit behind the corner of the window sometimes while resizing the window staggers and button sort of loses its place...

```
// Move floating button to stay visible in place when ever the window resizes 
void MyWindow::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent* event)
{
    if (m_fButton) {
        if (m_fButton->pattern() != RootFloatingButton::Pattern::Floating)
        m_fButton->tabWidgetChanged(tabWidget());
    else {
        if (m_fButton->x() > event->size().width())
        {
            m_fButton->move((event->size().width() + m_fButton->width()), (m_fButton->y()));
        }
        if (m_fButton->y() > event->size().height())
        {
            m_fButton->move((m_fButton->x()), (event->size().height() - m_fButton->height()));
        }
// this code below was first used to keep the button in place relative to the window when resized
        m_fButton->move(std::min(m_fButton->x(), event->size().width() + m_fButton->width()),
                        std::min(m_fButton->y(), event->size().height() + m_fButton->height()));
}
```

the code i mention below worked but only if the button remains away for bottom lower right corner once window from bottom corners passes it the button will no longer appear again...

Any idea how I can sort this problem out?

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Comment: Please indent your code properly and place the curly braces where they belong, especially using nested `if`s and `else`s. Right now the control flow (desired, as well as actual) is entirely unclear.